# Visual Studio 2017 Update fails. Why?

Tags: visual-studio, updates

I am trying to apply Visual Studio 2017 Update 15.7.4 by clicking on the Notification link in Visual Studio Notifications window. The updates fails with the following error. How do I determine which applications to close that migh be using the path?

[image]

Comment: Close all instances of visual studio

Comment: Do take the obvious counter-measures: reboot the machine, disable anti-malware.  Then use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know.

Comment: 1) Always run as administrator. 2) Try to close all the VS processes

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all the responses. I had to uninstall using the following command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe
```